# Unable to copy Lotus Notes text field's content to clipboard

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula

sometimes i'm unable to copy and paste the text content in a field of a form.

i try to do this:

```
FIELD ~$KeepPrivate:=~$KeepPrivate;
@SetField("$KeepPrivate";@Unavailable);
SELECT @All
```

but the situation is the same and i'm not able to copy and paste....
Someone can help me ?
thank's

Comment: What kind of field is it on form?

Comment: it's a editable text field that contain a text... i cannot copy the text contained in that field...

Comment: but you want to copy the text content form the field ~$KeepPrivate and paste it in the same field ~$KeepPrivate again. Or did i unterstand something wrong?

Comment: no, i want to copy the text contained in that field (for ex. the name of a person or phone number) and past it in .txt file or in a lotusnotes documeunt. But sometimes the ctrl+c do not copy in the clipboard the selected text that i want to copy.

Comment: Does "sometimes" depend on content or user or read/edit mode or something specific? Does it happen to other fields too or is it only about this one specific field?

Comment: mmm i think no because when the copy is "disable" i'm unable to copy everythings in lotus notes... text, docs, formula, script... nothing

Comment: Is it a RichText field?

Comment: no, is a simple text field

Comment: You said "sometimes the ctrl+c do not copy"- does that mean it works sometimes for this field and sometimes not? - If yes, does it depend on content or something else?

Comment: Does the document have a field "$KeepPrivate"? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=475&uid=swg21164209

Comment: You said "sometimes the ctrl+c do not copy"- does that mean it works sometimes for this field and sometimes not? Yes, exactlly, for example today it'wont copy the same field that i have copy yesterday, with the same content

Comment: "$KeepPrivate" is the first option that i have considered but no, it'isnt private

Comment: Does this happen when you are creating/editing a docuemnt, or when you are reading the document? Does this happen on only one computer, or on all computers? Does this happen for all documents created with this particular form? Or just for one particular document? Is the field in a section, in a table, a layout region, or just alone on the form? What happens if you move the field to a different location on the form?

Comment: Also, there is a feature in the Notes client called "Switch Form". I'm not sure where to find it in the menus of the more recent versions, but it used to be on the View menu when you were reading or editing a document. Can you create a new form in the database, make it completely empty except for having only this field on it, and use then use the "Switch Form" feature to view an existing document with this form and see what happens?

Comment: Also, you've said that $KeepPrivate is not enabled -- but did you check that in the document properties for specific docs that you are unable to copy? Or did you just check the properties of the form?  There's actually a relationship between $KeepPrivate and the ACL, which results on documents that are private even when you do not expect them to be. I wrote a blog post about it many years ago: http://poweroftheschwartz.com/web/blog/poweroftheschwartz.nsf/d6plinks/RSCZ-6JP4EY

Comment: Can you copy any of the data from that document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe property "Disable printing/forwarding/copying to clipboard" is set in form properties

[image]

It shouldn't be set to enable copying text to clipboard.

Another reason for not being able to copy field's text could be field property "Hide paragraph when document is Copied to the clipboard" although it has effect in read mode only.

[image].

Other possible reasons are described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&q1=%22Replicate%20or%20copy%20documents%22&uid=swg21164209&loc=en_US&cs=iso-8859-1&cc=us&lang=en). In case your document has a field "$KeepPrivate" then execute this formula on document:

```
FIELD $KeepPrivate := @DeleteField
```

Comment: in the form where i have the problem "disable printing..." and "copied to the clipboard" box are not selected

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this just go to Preferences / Basic Notes Client Configuration and on Additional options box enable (Enable alternate keyboard shortcuts (for example, CTRL+R=Reply)

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to know if you are using CTRL+C or CTRL+Insert.
Please try using **CTRL+Insert** once and see if you can achieve copying it to your clipboard.